# PHP Java bridge with PDFbox

Tags: java, php, pdfbox, php-java-bridge

I want to use [PDFbox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/index.html) with [PHP/Java bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/), because the only other option after a lot of research involves XPDF and my host won't allow shell_exec(). I have managed to setup the PHP/Java bridge and I have downloaded the PDFbox library but I have no idea what to do with the library to be able to use its API in PHP - how do I include it?

The current folder structure I have with the bridge is:

```
JavaBridge
    java (containing Java.inc and JavaProxy.php)
    WEB-INF
    index.php (containing the code to test that I can use the bridge)
```

I have no idea how Java works in details, I just want to use the APIs to parse PDF documents (something similar to [this example](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/examples/source.php?source=concat-old.php) but parsing instead of merging). So do I need to build, do I need to just copy the files in one of the folders...?

And a second question: following the instructions on the PHP/Java bridge I've setup tomcat. But it only works on localhost so far, when I copy the JavaBridge folder on my PHP server I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Could not connect to the JEE server 127.0.0.1:8080. Please start it. Or define('JAVA_HOSTS',9267); define('JAVA_SERVLET',false); before including 'Java.inc' and try again.

How do I get a JEE server then? If I use a java host will I be able to connect to it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a `lib` directory inside `WEB-INF`?

Comment: Place the pdfbox.jar within that directory, that should enable Java to see the PDFBox jar. Then, you should be able to invoke PDFBox through PHP how they are showing in the tutorial for the bridge.

Comment: Cool! Do I need to include it or just use `require_once ("java/Java.inc");`? Also do you have any idea about the JEE server question by any chance?

Comment: You shouldn't need to include it in PHP. I've never used the bridge you're referencing, however this is what I would do if I was in your position. I unfortunately do not know anything about the JEE server question.